Can't install module although dependancies are all satisfied?
I am trying to download a module. It worked before but 2 weeks ago it gave me an error, and I can't install it again...
I tried using the command:
conda install -c conda-forge montreal-forced-aligner
and
mamba install -c conda-forge montreal-forced-aligner
Although it seems not to be used normally to download MFA I also tried using pip. Even though it doesn't crash, the module was not installed (I can't import it).
Both worked before, but I get the error shown below: I am said not to have scikit<1.3, while I have 1.2.2<1.3, and it tries to download some weird 0.* versions.


Can you show the commands leading to this? E.g. how did you make this environment? How did you install the other packages (esp scikit-learn)? Easiest thing might be to make a completely new environment... If it's a Conda env, then install as few things as possible with pip.

I would try uninstalling the problematic packages, i.e. MFA, scikit, scikit-learn and all scikit* dependencies, including vc. What is your python version? Make sure it is a supported version, i.e, 3.10, 3.11, or 3.12.

I tried to install python 3.9, 3.10, 3.11, 3.12, it can install MFA but still doesnt work, i tried to uninstall them too, but still the same :/

Please post the output of conda list
